# Easiest way to print Array 1 in order its values appear in array 2?

Tags: python

Im not sure how to go about coding an array to have its values reordered in the order the same string values appear in another array.

For example:

```
Array1=[a,b,c]  
Array2 = [j,c,f,a,b,h]  
PrintedOutput=" c,a,b"
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; Please don't be alarmed if your question gets closed, it's in order to make space for more "interesting" questions. Meanwhile, I'd use something lie: `order = dict(x[::-1] for x in enumerate(b)); sorted(a, key=lambda e: order[e])`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming each element from `Array1` is guaranteed to occur in `Array2`, you can use

```
>>> sorted(Array1, key=Array2.index)
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!
This worked great

Answer (score 0):

Another, more efficient (if you make your first list a set), way to do this is with list comprehensions:

```py
>>> a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> a2 = ['j', 'c', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'h']
>>> [x for x in a2 if x in a1]
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

In particular, as the other answer noted, this relies on the fact that all the elements in your first array appear in your second array.  If any elements from the first array don't appear in the second array, they will be omitted in my answer, and will throw an error in the other answer.